# scala 2.11.8 how to fill an array

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-2.11

I want to create an array that contains the same value repeated for a very large number of times, say 1,000,000.

I was thinking to use something like Array.fill(1000000)(0). However, after reading the documentation for Scala 2.11.8, I found that there is no such members of Array in this version.

Is there any other ways that can create the array without using loop? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have your tried `fill` yourself? The fill method already existed in scala 2.11.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use range to iterate through required length (`1000000` times in your case) and then return a default value which is `0` in each iteration as below.

```
val arr:Array[Int] = (1 to 1000000 map(_ => 0)).toArray
```

Answer (score 5):

This will do the trick:

```
Array.fill[Int](1000000)(0)
```

Read more here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-list-class-examples

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.continually(0).take(1000000).toArray` would do that .. but *why in the world* would you want something like this???